# Display JSON output in a Grid?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, kendo-ui

can you help me with my problem? I need to bind a data from my mysql table. I can get the json values but I can't display it in the grid.

Here's what I did:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource:{
                transport: {
                    read: "<?php echo site_url('member/getMember'); ?>",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                schema:{
                    data: "data"
                }
            },
            height: 500,
            scrollable: true,
            selectable: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

My controller function:

```
    public function getMember(){

        $g = $this->members_model->getAllMember();

        echo json_encode($g->result_array());

    }
```

My model function:

```
   public function getAllMember(){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM member";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);

        return $result;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write "**json**" instead of "**jsonp**"

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource:{
                transport: {
                    read: "<?php echo site_url('member/getMember'); ?>",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                schema:{
                    data: "data"
                }
            },
            height: 500,
            scrollable: true,
            selectable: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Nice catch.  I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your model method is returning data?  Shouldn't your model method look like this instead?

```
public function getAllMember() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM member";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result()
}
```

$this->db->query($sql);  <-- this by itself does not return data.

**Update**

Sorry. I just noticed you're getting the results in the controller method. So, you're model method is good.

You shouldn't echo anything from your controller.  Ever.  Never do that.  Let the view layer handle that.

Render your view in the controller like this:

```
public function getMember(){

    $g = $this->members_model->getAllMember();
    $data = $g->result_array();
    $this->load->view('path/to/view/file', $data);

}
```

The code above will work, but you should really use result_array() in the model layer -- not the controller.

Can you paste the rest of your view file? I think this issue may be specific to kendoGrid's jQuery plugin, but I'll look a bit more.